# XHR local files from a local file

Tags: javascript, cors, xmlhttprequest

I have a local (file:///) HTML page that tries to AJAX resources from its local directory.  For years now Chrome has blanket forbidden all XHRs to file:/// URIs regardless of origin, which is annoying, but at least there's Firefox. But [recent Fx versions have started replicating this behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp).  This seems like a good time to solve the problem once and for all. So:

How do I mark an entire local directory (and preferably its subdirectories) as being a single origin for the purposes of XHR and CORS?

It would be nice if:

- It Just Worked on recent desktop Chrome and Firefox versions
- The constituent files were separate files for easy editing and not bundled up in some archive format

This sounds like just the kind of problem that MHTML or MAFF or webarchive would help with, except that they're not universally available, or are deprecated, or both.  Plus having the constituent files easily editable is important for my particular use case.

"Solutions" I'd rather avoid:

- Command line flags or browser options (I don't want to have to use Chrome's `--allow-file-access-from-file` or Fx's suggested `privacy.file_unique_origin` pref)
- Running a local web server just to serve up static files on a single machine
- Embedding my data in javascript code or massive data: URIs
- Making an Electr*n app

What's best practice here?

Comment: Simply: You can't. Each local file is treated as its own origin, so access across multiple local files is never considered "same origin".

Comment: Apart from the options you rather avoid, your out of luck.  Can you imagine if I created a website that did  an ajax request like -> `file://password.txt`  a bit of a security risk would you not say.?

Comment: @Keith - I think hexwab wants only `file://` URLs to be in the same origin as other `file://` URLs, so your making a website trying to use `file://` wouldn't matter, since that would be cross-origin from `http://` or `https://`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Still a bit of security risk though,.  What if my website offered a Javascript file as a download,.  The user then without thinking clicks open..  Easy done.

Comment: @Keith - No question there's a good reason why Chrome (and now Firefox) block this. :-)

Comment: `This seems like a good time to solve the problem once and for all`   Just an idea, have you ever considered using -> https://electronjs.org/  This allows you to have full control from a browser instance, it's basically a web-kit browser with a node.js backend..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's more specific than that. I don't want *all* file:/// URIs to be in the same origin: I understand how that's a security problem. I want to be able to carve out a separate little origin for just the files that are part of my app. I'm OK with having to make some kind of manifest file stating what's included in the origin.

Comment: @hexwab: I have the same need and the same problem for an app I'm trying to do for me

Answer (score 4):

> How do I mark an entire local directory (and preferably its subdirectories) as being a single origin for the purposes of XHR and CORS?

You can't. You'll have to use one of the solutions you'd rather avoid.

Comment: And this doesn't make any sense at all since the browser will happily load images from the same directory the HTML file sits in, and even from other directories via relative paths. And not just statically as defined in the HTML code, but also dynmically per JS update of the `img/@src` property. So why wouldn't the browser load `txt` data or whatnot from the exact same local origin? If security were such a concern, tons of ad crap, tracker cookies and megabyte sized JS libraries from the *wild world web* would surely be avoided.